# How to run logcat on multiple devices?

Tags: android, device, adb, logcat

How can I run logcat on multiple devices at the same time? "adb logcat" command gives an error:

```
error: more than one device and emulator
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Use the `-s` option of `adb`:

```
adb -s <serialnumber>
```

**Example**

```
C:\Users\lel>adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.198.101:5555    device
0123456789ABCDEF        device

adb -s 0123456789ABCDEF logcat
adb -s 192.168.198.101:5555 logcat
```

You can combine `grep` whit this, to get all lines that contain it.
an example is with `System.out`

Example:

```
 adb -s 192.168.198.101:5555 logcat | grep "System.out"
```

Comment: I guess I will pay more attention to adb parameters next time... Sorry for bringing up such an obvious problem. :)

Comment: how did you get the serialnumber ? I tried with adb devices but that give me this List of devices attached 
HT05XPL09783 device
100082a42935 device
and adb logcat -s 100082a42935 doesn't work

Comment: I found my stupid mistake it should stay like adb  -s 100082a42935 logcat

Answer (score 11):

I thought it might be useful. I have this script that helps me a lot. It logcats each device to a different file. To stop logging just press CTRL+C.

```
#! /bin/bash

devices=`adb devices | grep 'device$' | cut -f1`
pids=""

for device in $devices
do
    log_file="$device-`date +%d-%m-%H:%M:%S`.log"
    echo "Logging device $device to \"$log_file\""
    adb -s $device logcat -v threadtime > $log_file &
    pids="$pids $!"
done

echo "Children PIDs: $pids"

killemall()
{
    echo "Killing children (what a shame...)"

    for pid in $pids
    do
        echo "Killing $pid"
        kill -TERM $pid
    done
}

trap killemall INT

wait
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your device ip:
`adb -s device_ip:5555`