# Android adb & adbd

Tags: android, adb

I have next situation:
I got  2 version of `adb`  and 2 versions of `adbd` on 2 different devices.
How can i use both versions of `adb` from my workstation for these 2 devices.
I mean:
1 adb for 1 device.
2 adb for 2 device.

Now i have following situation:
Every time when i run another adb, previous adb server kills and new one starts.

How can I workaround it?

Comment: Please have a look at : 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203240/how-to-run-logcat-on-multiple-devices][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203240/how-to-run-logcat-on-multiple-devices

Comment: No i mean not this situation, i mean situation when you have 2 different adb files and you want use first for one phone and second for second phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking the wrong question. What I think you want is to run two adb commands at once on different phones. Is that correct?

If so what you are looking for is

```
adb -s DEVICE_SERIAL xxx
```

where DEVICE_SERIAL is the value shown when you run adb devices and xxx is the command you want to run. Use `adb devices` for a list of connected devices.

This only requires you to have one version of adb installed, just open up a new terminal and run the command for the different serial numbered device!

Comment: No I want to run 2 different adb for 2 different phones 
1st adb for 1st phone.
2nd adb for 2nd phone.
Trick with serial number doesn't help here.
I want use 2 different executable files (adb) from one machine from same user-account

Comment: why do you want to do that? What benefits do you expect to get from it?

Comment: I dont believe its possible to have both running at the same time as you have found, i suppose you might be able to get the source and change it but even then the amount of work required would be incredible. Especially as fundamentally, what do you expect to gain from this? Adb is pretty thoroughly tested so what do you expect to get fro testing two different versions?

Comment: I just want to use adb changed by me for one phone and regular adb for another.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understand the question correctly I believe he's trying to run two different versions of ADB at the same time.  If my assumption is correct then here is what you'd want to do.

Lets assume you have adb.1.0.29.exe and adb.1.0.39.exe on the root of the c: drive which were renamed from the adb.exe from the different versions of platform-tools SDK versions they were supplied in.

To run the ADB version contained within adb.1.0.29.exe all you have to do is what the linked articles say BUT be sure to call the proper exe for that version.  I used these adb version names as examples.  You can name the adb.exe whatever you want.

So you can call adb commands with different versions as follows,

c:\adb.1.0.29.exe -s serial_of_device adb_command

or

c:\adb.1.0.23.exe -s serial_of_device adb_command

Cheers,
-Rob

Comment: It was 4 years ago :) And the question was - how to run them simultaneously