# How to logcat multiple devices?

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, adb, genymotion

I have 2 genymotion emulators. If I watch for logcat inside adnroid studio by switching devices, it works fine but just for several minutes, then one of device logs becomes empty (logcat restart does not help in this case, only restart of android sudio meters)
I tried to open 2 terminal windows and fetch logcat from there [(as sugested in this topic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203240/how-to-run-logcat-on-multiple-devices), but:

```
adb devices
```

returns

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.57.102:5555 device
192.168.57.101:5555 device
```

Then I got

```
 adb -s 192.168.57.101.5555 logcat 
- waiting for device -
```

Or

```
adb -s device_ip:192.168.57.102.5555 logcat 
- waiting for device -
error: unknown host service
- waiting for device -
error: unknown host service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
adb -s 192.168.57.101.5555 logcat
```

should be

```
adb -s 192.168.57.101:5555 logcat
```

Note the difference in how the port is separated from the address.